# Java JFrame Both Frames Show At the Same Time Issue

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am making a program which has two frames.When i run the program both frames open at a same time.I want that when i run the program the ***first frame is open for 2 seconds then auto hides*** and ***then the second frame should show up***.

This is my code for frame 1:

```
public class Frame1 extends JFrame{

    private JLabel type;
    public Frame1(){    
    super("Frame 1");



    setLayout(null);
    type = new JLabel("This is Frame 1");
    type.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 51));
    type.setBounds(55, 227, 346, 52);
    add(type);


        setSize(500,600);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);

        setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Code for frame 2:

```
public class Frame2 extends JFrame{

    private JLabel text;

        public Frame2(){
        super("Frame 2");
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        text = new JLabel("This is Frame 2");
        text.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 36));
        text.setBounds(10, 66, 244, 52);
        getContentPane().add(text);


        setSize(300,350);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);

    }


}
```

Main:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Frame1 obj = new Frame1();

    Frame2 obj2 = new Frame2();

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

obj.setState(JFrame.ICONIFIED); 
You can use below code to get the first frame is open 
for 2 seconds then auto hide and then second frame:

```
public class Main { 

  public static void main(String[] args) {
Frame1 obj = new Frame1();
try {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    obj.setState(JFrame.ICONIFIED);
} catch (Exception e) {
}
Frame2 obj2 = new Frame2();
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change you main class like this...

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Frame1 obj = new Frame1();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {      
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    obj.setState(obj.ICONIFIED);

    Frame2 obj2 = new Frame2();

}
```

This will **minimize your first frame and show the second frame** .

Comment: @hamel123 a thread of execution is the smallest sequence of programmed instructions that can be managed independently by a scheduler. For more info go to javadocs... Follow the link.... docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer i pick it up.

Comment: if my answer helped you... mark it as accepted... so that other who search for it can be helped...